# code keeps throwing me an Exception

Tags: java

I have the next code which has to open a File given by the user. The adress in which the file is located is correct, but the problem is that it keeps throwing the exception FileNotFoundException and i can´t figure out what the problem is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class OpenFile{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName,name,r = "C:/Users/MyName/workspace/Proyect/";
        Scanner t = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Give me the name of the file: ");
        name = t.nextLine();
        t.close();
        fileName = r+name;
        try
        {
            File f = new File(fileName);
            RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(f,"r");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("cannot open file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd probably help to start by *printing* the full filename you're trying to access and seeing if it's what you expect.

Comment: any spelling mistakes in the filepath?

Comment: sout filepath .then check is it correct

Comment: Should Proyect be Project

Comment: Use `System.out.println(fileName);` to validate the input file name...

Comment: @PM77-1 I might be missing something, but `/` is a valid character to be used in a `String` "\" isn't and would need to be escaped, but under Windows, Java doesn't care if you use `/` or "\" ("\\") for path separators, Linux based OS do

Comment: It might be because of extra whitespace characters from the Scanner - try using `t.nextLine().trim()`

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions, at the very least, use `ex.printStackTrace` as they might provide more useful information

Comment: Generally (a part from poor resource management), the code works.  You will need to verify the input and ensure that the file does actually exists.  You can use `File#exists` to determine if the file does actually exist before you read it, but you need to do more debugging of the files are you trying to use...

Comment: your code works fine in my pc.

Comment: Permissions? No read perm to open the file perhaps?

Comment: Don't do this: `String fileName,name,r = "C:/Users/MyName/workspace/Proyect/";`

Comment: Show us a listing where you run the app once with `System.out.println(filename);` installed, and then immediately do a `dir` on C:/Users/MyName/workspace/Proyect/.

Comment: @user3105533 did u solve ur issue?

Answer (score 0):

**Couple Of Tips:**

**First**, you should replace `/` this with `File.separator`

```
 "CFile.separatorUsersFile.separatorMyNameFile.separatorworkspaceFile.separatorProyect`File.separator"
```

**Second**, your variables `fileName` and `name` are not intilized
 it is better to define them like this.

```
       String fileName ="";
       String name="";      <------ which  is more readable
```

**Third** it is good to put your scanner in try catch block with resources so there is not need to be close manualy like

```
  try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)){
  }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
  }
```

**Hope these tips help you to solve your issue**

Comment: He should replace `/` with `File.separator`, **NOT** `\\ `

Comment: And don't go crazy with the bold next time please.

Comment: @Rogue is it better now?

Comment: @KickButtowski You're still suggesting to use `\\ `, so I don't see how it's better no

Comment: @Rogue but \\ works for me all the time, so File.speartor is better answer?

Comment: @KickButtowski Using the separator is a system-independent solution, whereas just putting `\\ ` allows it to break on some file management systems. On another note, the variable initialization tip is completely optional and in some cases not even necessary.

Comment: @Rogue I will change my answer, so I should put File.speartor insead of / ya?

Comment: can whoever voted me down let me know why? so I can understand my mistake plz thank you